# Ajax is not working in my Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have following code to make an ajax request to my controller's method to get the content type of the given url :

```
    $("#wiki_form_url").change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/wiki_forms/content",
            data: {
                input_url: $("#wiki_form_url").val()
            },
            dataType: "text"
        }).done(function (data) {
                    // `data` contains the content-type
                    alert('Success');
                    console.log(data);
//                    alert(data);
                }).fail(function () {
                    alert("failed AJAX call");
                });
    });
```

There is a method in my wiki_forms controller named content and inside that I am doing :

```
  def content

    req = open(params[:input_url])
    render :text => req.content_type
    puts  "type is : #{req.content_type}"

  end
```

in my route.rb file  I have :

```
 match "/wiki_forms/content" => 'wiki_forms#content'
```

But, when I try to make the ajax request I get error. My console looks like this :

```
Started GET "/wiki_forms/content?input_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ofdp.org%2Fbenchmark_indices%2F25" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-28 14:08:42 -0400
Processing by WikiFormsController#show as TEXT
  Parameters: {"input_url"=>"http://www.ofdp.org/benchmark_indices/25", "id"=>"content"}
  WikiForm Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "wiki_forms".* FROM "wiki_forms" WHERE "wiki_forms"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "content"]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find WikiForm with id=content):
  app/controllers/wiki_forms_controller.rb:23:in `show'
```

Why is show method is getting called here as I specified the content method in my ajax call? How to make this work ? Please help

**EDIT_1 :**

**rake routes**

```
        wiki_forms GET    /wiki_forms(.:format)          wiki_forms#index
                   POST   /wiki_forms(.:format)          wiki_forms#create
     new_wiki_form GET    /wiki_forms/new(.:format)      wiki_forms#new
    edit_wiki_form GET    /wiki_forms/:id/edit(.:format) wiki_forms#edit
         wiki_form GET    /wiki_forms/:id(.:format)      wiki_forms#show
                   PUT    /wiki_forms/:id(.:format)      wiki_forms#update
                   DELETE /wiki_forms/:id(.:format)      wiki_forms#destroy
              root        /                              wiki_forms#index
wiki_forms_content        /wiki_forms/content(.:format)  wiki_forms#content
```

Comment: Your `route.rb` shows one thing. Can you show us the output of `rake routes` instead?

Comment: Does your javascript console show any errors?

Comment: GET http://localhost:3000/wiki_forms/content?input_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ofdp.org%2Fbenchmark_indices%2F25 404 (Not Found) 

this is the error that is shown in my javascript console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ordering of your `routes.rb` file matters.

`rake routes` shows

```
        wiki_forms GET    /wiki_forms(.:format)          wiki_forms#index
                   POST   /wiki_forms(.:format)          wiki_forms#create
     new_wiki_form GET    /wiki_forms/new(.:format)      wiki_forms#new
    edit_wiki_form GET    /wiki_forms/:id/edit(.:format) wiki_forms#edit
         wiki_form GET    /wiki_forms/:id(.:format)      wiki_forms#show
                   PUT    /wiki_forms/:id(.:format)      wiki_forms#update
                   DELETE /wiki_forms/:id(.:format)      wiki_forms#destroy
              root        /                              wiki_forms#index
wiki_forms_content        /wiki_forms/content(.:format)  wiki_forms#content
```

So

```
         wiki_form GET    /wiki_forms/:id(.:format)      wiki_forms#show
```

is matching first, with `:id` having the value string "content"

Move your

```
match "/wiki_forms/content" => 'wiki_forms#content'
```

higher up in `routes.rb`.